# Selenium RC Error when running tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I get this error when running a number of tests in seleniums Bromine, The selenium RC version 1.0.2 outputs this:

WARN - GET /selenium-server/driver/?cmd=testComplete&1=&2=&sessionId=1274d41621c64fc08c1e7ea0a58f260b HTTP/1.0 java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected command json={command:"open",target:"/Library/Security/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fIndex.aspx",value:""} in place before new command selectWindow could be added at org.openqa.selenium.server.CommandQueue.doCommandWithoutWaitingForARe
sponse(CommandQueue.java:121)

Any ideas

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had to track this problem on our testing environment and it appears, that the reason was Firefox crashing. If this error follows two 'Command timed out' exceptions, then your browser probably crashed or hanged.

Upon inspection of code of Selenium RC I realized that 'Unexpected command' error appears when there is an overflow in command queue. This can be caused by lack of responses from the browser, so if browser crashes, you end up receiving this error.

Check your dmesg logs (or some other logs, if not under Linux) to see, if there is anything suspicious. In my case there were entries like this:

```
plugin-containe[30867]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f07a6ff503d sp 00007f079d593260 error 4 in libxul.so[7f07a6265000+146f000]
```

libxul.so and plugin-container are modules of Firefox. Upgrading it to newer version helped in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also seeing this IllegalStateException, much too frequently.  Its occurrence seems random, as if something in Selenium isn't synchronized properly.  I have seen it several times in connection with a TestNG Listener that calls selenium to do a screen capture, but again, it's unpredictable.