# What is the cause for the SeleniumException:ERROR ServerException: : unexpected command json?

Tags: selenium-rc

I run a large number of tests during off work times using Selenium RC and TestNG. I also take screenshots for every test and store it using
   selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot(path, filename);

A lot of my tests have been failing and this is the error message I get-

com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR Server Exception: unexpected command json{command:"captureEntirePageScreenshot",target:"c:\abc\TestProject\screenshots\test1.png"} in place before new command captureEntirePageScreenshot could be added

I am trying to understand why is this generated and is it related to capturing screenshots. Has anyone encountered this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
captureEntirePageScreenshot(c:\abc\TestProject\screenshots\test1, #CCFFDD);
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a result of a browser crash.  I describe this case in a bit more detail in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345152/1075874).